# Detecting Full Speed USB Device on Android

Tags: android, usb

I am trying connect full speed device to android tablet, but I am getting below error message. So please let me know is there any way to solve this?.

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

7>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: GetStatus port:2 status 001002 0  ACK POWER sig=se0 CS

4>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: port 2 cannot be enabled

4>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: Maybe your device is not a high speed device?

4>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: USB host (EHCI) controller does not support full speed

or low speed device on it's root port.

4>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: Please connect full/low speed device via a high speed

ub.

3>hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2

7>hub 1-0:1.0: state 7 ports 3 chg 0000 evt 0004

7>hub 1-0:1.0: state 7 ports 3 chg 0000 evt 0004

7>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: GetStatus port:2 status 001803 0  ACK POWER sig=j CSC

ONNECT

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2, status 0501, change 0001, 480 Mb/s

7>hub 1-0:1.0: debounce: port 2: total 100ms stable 100ms status 0x501

7>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: port 2 full speed --> companion

7>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: GetStatus port:2 status 001801 0  ACK POWER sig=j CONN

CT

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 50ms

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port_wait_reset: err = -16

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not enabled, trying reset again...

7>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: port 2 full speed --> companion

7>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: GetStatus port:2 status 001801 0  ACK POWER sig=j CONN
CT

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port_wait_reset: err = -16

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not enabled, trying reset again...

7>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: port 2 full speed --> companion

7>ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: GetStatus port:2 status 001801 0  ACK POWER sig=j CONN
CT

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

7>hub 1-0:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 200ms

Comment: Have you tried connecting the periperhal device via an external hub as suggested in the error message, which indicates that the Android device's USB host controller does not support full-speed peripherals?

Answer (score 0):

The slave is refusing to step down, probably because the host keeps advertising 2.0, but cannot actually deliver it. It looks as if you have a poorly provisioned Android device. A cheap tablet by any chance?

Comment: This doesn't seem consistent with the error message "USB host (EHCI) controller does not support full speed or low speed device on it's root port" or the problem statement "I am trying connect full speed device to android tablet"